# Header not changing URL if one input box was filled

Tags: php, html

I've been working on a website using html, css, and PHP. Currently I'm trying to make it so when a person tries to register, but for example leaves the Username empty, the URL Error should be something like http://localhost/Presence/PresenceSignup.php?error=emptyfields%uid=&mail=123123. But the URL just stays as 
http://localhost/Presence/PresenceSignup.php?error=emptyfields%uid=&mail=

```
<?php
    require "PresenceNavbar.php"
?>
<link href="css/SignUp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<body scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden">
    <main>
        <div>
            <section class ="SignupSheet">
                <img src="assets/Keyhole.png" width="130" class="avatar">
            <h1>Sign Up</h1>
            <form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
                <p>Username</p>
                <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
                <p>E-mail</p>
                <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail">
                <p>Password</p>
                <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
                <p>Repeat Password</p>
                <input type="password" name="pwd-repeat" placeholder="Repeat Password">
                <input type="submit" name="signup-submit" id="signup-submit" value="Sign Up">
            </form>
            </section>
        </div>

    </main>
</body>
```

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['signup-submit']))
{
    require 'dbh.inc.php';


    $username = $_post['uid'];
    $email = $_post['mail'];
    $password = $_post['pwd'];
    $passwordrepeat = $_post['pwd-repeat'];

    if (empty($username) || empty($username) || empty($username) || empty($username))
    {
        header("Location: ../PresenceSignup.php?error=emptyfields%uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    }

}
```

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
$dBName = "loginsystem";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);

if (!$conn)
{
    die("Connection Failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to redirect just to show an error message? Just render the page directly.

Comment: Sorry, first time using this website

Comment: On your second script you checked several times the username, use this condition `if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordrepea)){...}` instead to check other values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `&` instead of `%` and `$_POST` instead of `$_post`. try this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['signup-submit']))
{
    require 'dbh.inc.php';


    $username = $_POST['uid'];
    $email = $_POST['mail'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $passwordrepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];

    if (empty($username) || empty($username) || empty($username) || empty($username))
    {

        header("Location: ../PresenceSignup.php?error=emptyfields&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Just tried it, no change URL still only prints out 
/PresenceSignup.php?error=emptyfields&uid=&mail="

Comment: Are you filling the `email` input box ?

Comment: I think I got the error, you were using `$_post` in small letters, it should be `$_POST` in capital letters. Updated the answer. Try now.

Comment: Yea, on my form I filled out the email, password, and the password repeat box, leaving the Username box empty.

Comment: Okay, yeah that fixed the problem thank you, been working on this for a while and didnt realize my syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Do not construct your URL manually like this. This is very insecure and error prone. PHP has a solution for this. Use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

As an example you could use it this way:

```
$username = $_POST['uid'];
$email = $_POST['mail'];
$password = $_POST['pwd'];
$passwordrepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];

if (empty($username)) {
    $queryStringArray = [
        'error' => 'emptyfields',
        'uid' => $username,
        'mail' => $email,
    ];
    header("Location: ../PresenceSignup.php?".http_build_query($queryStringArray));
    exit();
}
```

Additionally, as pointed out but others it is `$_POST` not `$_post` and you checked 4 times for `empty($username)`.